# Avoid actions on child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button called "Add New Row" which creates a new row, but within this row you can create other rows, so what I did was add an action to the button "Add new row" to activate the button + that creates the Row, the problem is that it not only activates the + button that generates a general row, but also activates the + buttons of the child rows, as I could do so that it only activates the + button of the main field, I will leave a example of what I'm doing.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            jQuery("#addRow").click(function(){
                jQuery('.field_457865682 .actions a[data-event="add-row"]').trigger('click');
            });

            jQuery('.field_457865682 a[data-event="add-row"]').click(function(){
                alert( 'Row added successfully' );
            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="addRow">Add New Row</a>

    <div class="field field_457865682">

        <div class="field field_874698465">
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="#" data-event="add-row">+</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="actions">
            <a href="#" data-event="add-row">+</a>
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

As you can see, it activates the function twice because it is clicking on both + buttons but I would like it to only do it with the main button.

I've tried stop propagation but it doesn't work, I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this instead of simulating a click.

```
$('#addRow, a[data-event="add-row"]').on('click', function(){
 alert( 'Row added successfully' );
})
```

This way events are not triggered unexpectedly